# Why is xslt converter ignoring the content of <link>-tag

Tags: xslt

When I put forexample this in my xslt-stylesheet:

```
<link><xsl:text>test</xsl:text></link>
```

Or this:

```
<link>test</link>
```

I get the following result:

```
<link xmlns=""></link>
```

This however:

```
<linkb>test</linkb>
```

Render the following result:

```
<linkb xmlns="">test</linkb>
```

The rest of the xslt does not seem to make any difference, i've tried it in several different and empty xslt-stylesheets

This problem appears in backend conversion (php) aswell as frontend-konversion in chrome browser (but not in Firefox)

Example of error:
dev.resihop.nu
(right above the footer)

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more of your stylesheet if we are to debug it. Have you tried it with a standalone processor (i.e. not in a browser)?

Comment: This is not a well-defined question. Please, provide: 1. A complete (but as minimal as possible) XML document. 2, A complete (but as minimal as possible) XSLT stylesheet. 3. The result of the transformation. 4. What is wrong with the result.

Comment: By "following result", do you mean what is getting rendered by the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an XSLT issue.

```
<link xmlns="">
```

Is rendered by Chrome, problem is with built-in browser CSS:

```
link {
    display: none;
    }
```

You can see this with Chrome developer toolbar (just press Ctrl-Shift-I). I think it's also a reason of no rendering of tag's content. I guess Chrome just don't like elements with such names and treats them specifically.

**Edit**. And actually I do understand, why. Because of the `link` tag, which we all use in `head` section.

In fact the simpliest way to avoid issues like yours -- is to pick any suitable (X)HTML doctype and make your code valid, according to that doctype.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not declare an output method, which defaulted to HTML.

Try:

`<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>`

Best regards!